# Is there a music player can display the song words and scrobble to Last.fm?

Tags: music-player

Currently, my favourite music player is Winamp for my HTC Incredible S. Because it supports scrobbling with the Last.fm app and syncs with my Winamp in PC.

However, some of my mp3 files saved the song words and I can't find how to display those words (of the playing song) in Winamp. Likes the music player in iPod Touch / iPhone.

Is there a music player that supports those 2 features? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the Market description, [Astro Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.astroplayer&feature=search_result) looks like it might.

Comment: I have tried about 15 mins. It's a powerful player. It's just what I need!
However, it does not support the lyrics and cover art in m4a files. Also, I can't find shuffle function.
But it's enough for me. Thanks! :)